# How does Solr's schema-less feature work? How to revert it to classic schema?

Tags: solr, solr5

Just found that **Solr 5** doesn't require a schema file to be predefined and it generates the schema, based on the indexing being performed. I would like to know how does this work in the background?

And whether it's a good practice or not? Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[The schemaless feature has been in Solr since version 4.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4658). But it might be more stable only now as [a concurrency issue with it was fixed in 4.10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6137).

It is also called managed schema. When you configure Solr to use managed schema, Solr uses a special UpdateRequestProcessor to intercept document indexing requests and it guesses field types.

Solr starts with your `schema.xml` file and creates a new file called, by default, `managed-schema` to store all the inferred schema information. This file is automatically overwritten by Solr as it detects changes to the schema.

You should then use the [Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API) if you want to make changes to the Schema. See also the [Schemaless Mode documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode).

#### How to change Solr managed schema to classic schema

Stop Solr: `$ bin/solr stop`

Go to `server/solr/mycore/conf`, where "mycore" is the name of your core/collection.

Edit `solrconfig.xml`:

- search for `<schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">` and comment the whole element
- search for `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` and uncomment it
- search for the `<initParams>` element that refers to `add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema` and comment out the whole `<initParams>...</initParams>`

Rename `managed-schema` to `schema.xml` and you are done.

You can now start Solr again: `$ bin/solr start`, go to http://localhost:8983/solr/#/mycore/documents and check that Solr now refuses to index a document with a new field not yet specified in `schema.xml`.

### Is it a good practice? When to use it?

It depends on what you want. If you want to enforce a specific document structure (e.g. to make sure that all docs are "well-formed" according to your definition), then you want to use the classical schema management.

If on the other hand you don't know upfront what the doc structure is then you might want to use the schema-less feature.

### Limits

While it is called schema-less, there are limits to the kinds of structures that you can index. This is true both for Solr and Elasticsearch, by the way. For example, if you first index this doc:

```js
{"name":"John Doe"}
```

then you will get an error if you try to index a doc like that next:

```js
{"name": {
   "first": "Daniel",
   "second": "Dennett"
   }
}
```

That is because in the first case the field `name` was of type string while in the second case it is an object.

If you would like to use indexing which goes beyond these limitations then you could use [SIREn](http://siren.solutions/) - it is an [open source](https://github.com/sindicetech/siren) semi-structured information retrieval engine which is implemented as a plugin for both Solr and Elasticsearch. (*Disclaimer: I worked for the company that develops SIREn*)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you help me understand how to disable schemaless mode? Any example would be great!

Comment: @Krunal updated the answer with steps to change managed schema back to classic schema

Comment: Thanks for making an update! I will shortly test it and update the results here.

Comment: I continue to recommend to my clients that they use the unmanaged schema. The reason is I tend to version control solr home directories. A schema.xml, solrconfig, etc file IMO should be treated as development artifacts.

Comment: it is the best answer I read about this subject in solr

Answer (score 1):

This is so called schemaless mode in Solr. I don't know about internal details, how it's implemented, etc.

```
bin/solr start -e schemaless
```

This snippet above will start Solr in schemaless mode, if you don't do that, it will work as usual.

For more information on schemaless, take a look here -  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode

Comment: Hi, can you help me understand how to disable schemaless mode? I think its the default one, that started automatically.

Comment: just run it as usual, or use classic schema factory

Comment: I'm running it as usual, but still it runs schemaless mode. Any idea how to use classic schema factory? Note that I'm running this on Windows