# Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id while indexing pdf files in Solr 6.2.1 version

Tags: pdf, solr

I am very new to Solr. I am using Solr 6.2.1 version and working on windows. In that I could be indexed .csv,.json files. But while I am indexing the PDF files I am facing issue like "**Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id**".

Here I used command for creating Core,

C:\Solr\solr-6.2.1\bin>solr create -c Testcollection -d basic_configs

and command for Indexing pdf ,
C:\Solr\solr-6.2.1\example\exampledocs>java -Dtype=application/pdf -Durl=http://
localhost:8983/solr/Testcollection/update/extract -jar post.jar one_order_model.
pdf

Please suggest me that how can fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Nag[image]

Comment: Some of your document won't have the field `id` but it is required  (uniqueKey field) hence the error. A solution is to tell Solr to generate a unique key when he needs it, see if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932280/solr-6-2-1-uniquefield-not-work/39933700

Comment: Thank you for response. I followed above link ,but still I am getting same error.